# Windows stopped booting after a restart

Tags: windows, boot, gpt, windows-11

Please help me kindly. My PC is really important to me.
I upgraded my PC from windows 10 to 11 using the dev channel. Now today I restarted it and it is not booting anymore. The Windows Boot Manager from the select boot priority place in bios disappeared. I have a windows DVD with windows 10. Now what can I do?
There must be a way to get my lost boot files back, there must be a CMD command or something. Can anyone help me ?
I can't install windows from the DVD with windows 10 because I have GPT disk but that DVD is MBR. Bootrec rebuildbcd says the requested device could not be found.

Comment: Golden rule: Never install beta software on a mission-critical machine without a clear [tested] path to restore.

Comment: Is your hard disk still being recognized?  In your recovery environment open `diskpart` and run `list disk` and `list volume`

Comment: Speaking from 35 years of experience with Microsoft products (which I use and like)... **Never take the first release.** Windows 11 is in beta - meaning that it almost certainly has bugs. They will not give it to you without your signing a release!

Comment: Restart, F8 repeatedly to get into Safe Mode. If that works (don't know from here) roll back the update. I have a non-critical machine with Insider Winn 11 and it is working fine. I checked to ensure roll back will work.